# Probability calculation of genetics

Tags: probability

A genetic locus can have two alleles, A and B. Since each person has two copies (one from each chromosome), there are three genotypes: homozy- gous AA, BB, and heterozygous AB. Note that since we usually do not know the descent of each allele (father or mother), AB and BA are the same genotype. Suppose the frequency of allele A in a population is 90%. Suppose each individual has two independent alleles at this locus. What is the probability that a person’s phenotype is AA, if we know that he has at least one copy of the A allele?

My calculation is as follows:

$$\frac{P(AA)}{P(AA)+P(AB)} = \frac{0.9 \cdot 0.9}{0.9 \cdot 0.9 + 0.9 \cdot 0.1} = 0.9$$

Is this correct?
Thanks for help!

I see one answer says that "AB" stands for "AB" and "BA", but "AB" and "BA" are the same genotype, why should we consider "AB" in two different ways and double the probability?

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers. You should be able to comment on any part of your own questions, including the answers, independent of reputation. If you weren't able to comment on my answer, it was probably because you were using a different account by the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite – you didn't account for the fact that AB occurs in two different ways – "AB" stands for AB and BA combined, and the probability for this is $0.9\cdot0.1+0.1\cdot0.9=2\cdot0.9\cdot0.1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have a further question: since "AB" and "BA" are the same genotype, why should we consider "AB" in two different ways and double the probability?

Comment: @Emily: Try adding up the probabilities for the genotypes. The way you're calculating them, they don't add up to $1$. If two alleles are drawn randomly, there are four possible outcomes. The fact that we regard two of these outcomes as the same genotype doesn't change the probabilities. Imagine we found out that people with A from the father and B from the mother had very slightly darker hair than people with A from the mother and B from the father. Would that suddenly double the probability because the two outcomes have become distinguishable?

Comment: Yes, the probability would double if the two outcomes are different, but even if they are the same, the probability will still double? So the total probability of genotypes is: P(AA)+P(AB)+P(BA)+P(BB)=0.9*0.9+0.9*0.1+0.1*0.9+0.1*0.1=1?

Comment: @Emily: That's right. So the denominator in the question should be $0.9\cdot0.9+0.9\cdot0.1+0.1\cdot0.9$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry for the previous mess, since I'm a new user.